# Migrating from dsPIC to 32-bit PICs

Tags: pic, automotive, can

We have a successful CAN gateway product based on dsPIC33EP. The firmware is quite complicated and took years to develop. Written in C, the main loop calls many state machines, which each are quite portable to other platforms. Of course, the low level code is tailored specifically to dsPIC.

My job is to make a second generation hardware within 6 months. My dilemma is, whether I should stick to the dsPIC, or take my chances and go to 32-bit PIC33MZ or perhaps another 32-bit processor like Infineon TriCore TC1797.

The main reason I am considering the move, is that the current design is using a lot of computational capacity of dsPIC, and modern vehicles have even faster CAN communication and I am fearing the possibility of not being able to keep up with future vehicles.

I am an experienced designer, and know all the risks. This question is specifically asking those, who did such a migration in recent time and could share with me the actual experience.

Comment: There are some holes in you question. Which dsPIC are you using?  If your in the dsPIC33F family then going to the dsPIC33EP will get you some more speed. Which PIC32 chips are you looking at? The PIC32MX is mature (least silicon bugs) but the PIC32MZ is faster and newer but has more silicon bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am fearing the possibility of not being able to keep up with future vehicles.

Two options / risks:

1) if your current dspic isn't fast enough, see if there is a faster dspic. this route has the minimum amount of risk.

2) move to a faster chip. lots of them out there. and if the existing code is well laid out, porting to a new chip isn't going to be too difficult. this route has the maximum amount of flexibility, as well as risk.

if I were you, I would stay in the current dspic family as long as you can, especially if you use lots of dspic-specific processing.

if you have to move, pick one that has the peripherals, and then the processing power. profile your code and get a sense as to how much of processing it does. that will get you what the target chip looks like at a minimum.

you should also look into other aspects of the chip, like its ability to work in a rough environment. older chips like pic tend to be pretty good in that department. I would go to an automotive vendor first, like renesas, freescale, and infineon. stay away from the non-automotive guys as long as you can.